# How to delete the person's records, after delete the app? Is there a way?

Tags: ios8, xcode6, cloudkit

For example, one of the users creates random records, which are uploaded to public database in CloudKit, and some point, this person deletes the app, but his/her records are still existing. Because its a public database it counts against the free limits, so i should take care about it. Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to detect if a user removed the app from his phone or if he is just not using the app. What you could do is selecting all users with no activity in that past X months and if there is no recent activity, then delete these users. As you probably do not want to start this delete action from a random iPhone, you could create an OS X app that is connected to the same data container.

You could create a CKQuery for searching a recordID like this:

```
var query = CKQuery(recordType: recordType, predicate: NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", "creatorUserRecordID" ,CKReference(recordID: theSearchRecordId, action: CKReferenceAction.None)))
```

Where theSearchRecordId is the recordID.recordName that you are looking for. And you have to do this for each recordType that you have in your container. You do have to set the creatorUserRecorID field searchable in the CloudKit dashboard

Comment: Hm..that could work. Thanks! And how could you fetch a specific person's records? All of them?

Comment: I added the query that you can use to the answer.